# Error : More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/LICENSE'

Tags: java, android, google-translate

I having android app where I'm using google translate API 
When I build, I got Error :
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/LICENSE'

Answer (score 2):

try adding

```
packagingOptions {

        pickFirst "**"
    }
```

OR

```
packagingOptions {
   pickFirst  'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```

OR

```
packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding these lines in your app level gradle file

```
packagingOptions {
  exclude 'project.properties'
  exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
  exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
  exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
}
```